# How to add custom table in C# Form

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a simple program that shows data from SQL Server table in Windows form but I know only one way to show it which is DataGrid. But DataGrid cannot display table how we wants other to see. I want to draw custom table with my table headings and only selected columns. Is there any class which allows us to do this?

Comment: We can't be specific since you don't specify *why* a `DataGrid` isn't suited for the task.  But there are plenty of other controls available, particularly from vendors like Telerik and other competitors of theirs.  Or you can build your own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: _I want to draw custom table with my table headings and only selected columns._ A DataGridView will let you do this just fine. - Please make sure you are clear about what you are doing (__and tag your question accordingly!!))__: Winforms with DataGridviews, WPF with DataGrid or actaully the old and outdated DataView from the last century.. In any case, __do not__ simply write a lazy-bone `select * from..` but pick and name your columns!